# what does ">&" mean when followed by a file name?

Tags: shell

I encountered a strange command when using Bourne Shell:

`echo 123 >& result`

Typically I would expect something like `echo 123 > result 2>&1`, I never expect `>&` would be followed by a file name.

But to my surprise, when I execute this command in shell, the result is correct, it did create a file named "result", and this file contained text "123".

I am rather confused by this grammar. Can anyone explain this to me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Bash extension meaning redirect both stdout and stderr to the result file.

A portable way to achieve the same with POSIX compliant shells would be:

```
echo 123 >bar 2>&1
```

As "echo 123" is unlikely to output anything on stderr, that syntax is useless here.

Here is a example showing it working:

```
(echo stderr 1>&2;echo stdout) >& foo

(echo stderr 1>&2;echo stdout) >bar 2>&1
```

Comment: I also find that csh doesn't support 2>&1, so using >& is one feasible way to redirect stderr to stdout in csh.

Answer (score 1):

File descriptor of STDOUT is 1 which is used by default if you do not mention any file descriptor explicitly. So if I remember it correctly `echo 123 >& result` is same as `echo 123 1>&1 result`

Comment: so here `&` is actually redundant since its just redirecting stdout to stdout ?

Comment: I've tested it and it does not seem to be true. `echo 123 >& x` outputs `123` to a file named `x`

Comment: Your guess is incorrect. This syntax is a bashism and affects stderr output.

Answer (score 1):

case solved :

`echo 123 >& result` is equivalent to `echo 123 > result 2>&1`

Comment: Please share how did you test it?

Comment: @Aziz Shaikh I happened  to write a program which outputs something to stderr, you can write like this:
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc,char ** argv)
{
        fprintf(stdout,"this will go to stdout\n");
        fprintf(stderr,"this will go to stderr\n");
        return 0;
} and compile it to get a.out, when you call ./a.out > result, you will see that "stdout" line will appear in result file and "stderr" line appear in screen , when you call ./a.out >& result, you will find that both "stdout" and "stderr" line will appear in result.

Comment: No need to use C, you can do the same with a simple shell command (see my reply).